# Python Kivy: on_press without using root

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

Trying to work through the "Creating Apps in Kivy" book by Dusty Phillips, but there is a section that is pretty vague and is resulting in code that does not run correctly. I believe I know the issue, but not how to solve it.

Here is my .kv file:

```
WeatherRoot:

<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        search_input: search_box
        search_results: search_results_list

        BoxLayout:
            height: '48dp'
            size_hint_y:None
            TextInput:
                multiline:False
                write_tab:False
                id: search_box
                size_hint_x:50
                on_text_validate: root.search_location()
            Button:
                text:'Search'
                size_hint_x:25
                on_press: root.search_location()
            Button:
                text:'Current Location'
                size_hint_x:25

        ListView:
            id: search_results_list
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[],cls=ListItemButton)
```

Because on_press and on_text_validate go to root, and my root (in this case the WeatherRoot) does not contain the search_location() function, this crashes when I try to do a search.

Here is my python code:

```
from kivy.app import App from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

owm_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'

class WeatherRoot(BoxLayout):   
  pass

class AddLocationForm(BoxLayout):   
  search_input = ObjectProperty()

  def search_location(self):
    search_template = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={}&type=like&APPID='+ owm_key
    search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
    request = UrlRequest(search_url,self.found_location)

  def found_location(self,request,data):
    data = json.loadS(data.decode()) if not isinstance(data,dict) else data
    cities = ['{} ({})'.format(d['name'],d['sys']['country']) for d in data['list']]

    self.search_results.item_strings = cities
    self.search_results.adapter.data.clear()
    self.search_results.adapter.data.extend(cities)
    self.search_results.__trigger__reset_populate()

class WeatherApp(App):   
  pass

if __name__ == '__main__':   WeatherApp().run()
```

Because my WeatherRoot class is empty, using

```
root.search_location()
```

does nothing. Is there any way to reference not the root, but "one level up"? On another note, has anyone else worked their way through this book, and how did you handle this portion?

Thanks!
Dave

Answer (score 0):

This ended up working for me, just had to give the "one level up" widget an id, and reference it:

```
WeatherRoot:

<WeatherRoot>:
    AddLocationForm:
        id: addlocationform
        orientation: 'vertical'
        search_input: search_box
        search_results: search_results_list

        BoxLayout:
            height: '48dp'
            size_hint_y:None
            TextInput:
                multiline:False
                write_tab:False
                id: search_box
                size_hint_x:50
                on_text_validate: addlocationform.search_location()
            Button:
                text:'Search'
                size_hint_x:25
                on_press: addlocationform.search_location()
            Button:
                text:'Current Location'
                size_hint_x:25

        ListView:
            id: search_results_list
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[],cls=ListItemButton)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `AddLocationForm` by giving it an id.
Try like this:

```
AddLocationForm:
    id: form
```

Then you can access it ike this:

```
    BoxLayout:
        height: '48dp'
        size_hint_y:None
        TextInput:
            multiline:False
            write_tab:False
            id: search_box
            size_hint_x:50
            on_text_validate: form.search_location()
        Button:
            text:'Search'
            size_hint_x:25
            on_press: form.search_location()
```